# How to exclude folder from indexer in eclipse programatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

We have a big project. Once it is imported then indexer is taking much time.
So we planned to exclude some folder which are not required for indexing.

When we add the folder in Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->source location manually it works fine.

Now I want to implement the same in code.

Please help me.

Comment: Which of the many indexers in Eclipse are you asking about? C++ at a guess.

Comment: Yes C/C++ indexer.

Answer (score 1):

The method I use to exclude folders from the build (and thus from indexing) is `Right-click on folder -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Exclude resource from build`.

If you'd like to do this programmatically, the API to call is `ICResourceDescription.setExcluded()` (this is what that checkbox [does](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/ui/newui/AbstractPage.java#n335)).

The resource description for the folder can be obtained via `ICConfigurationDescription.getResourceDescription(IPath)`.

The configuration description can be obtained via `ICProjectDescription.getDefaultSettingConfiguration()`.

The project description can be obtained via `CoreModel.getProjectDescription(IProject)`.

Comment: Below code didn't work...                                                                         IPath newPath = new Path("exclude folder relative path");                                                                                                     
ICProjectDescription desc = CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescriptionManager().getProjectDescription(project, false);
ICConfigurationDescription config = desc.getDefaultSettingConfiguration();
            config.getResourceDescription(newPath, false).setExcluded(true);

Comment: @Sunil: After running this code, if you then check the folder's `Properties -> C/C++ Build` in the UI, is the "Exclude resource from build" checkbox now checked?

Comment: No "Exclude resource from build" checkbox is not checked. setExcluded(true) is not working properly. Till getResourceDescription is working without any issue.

Comment: boolean exclude = true;
            IManagedBuildInfo buildInfo = ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(project);
            IConfiguration activeConfig = buildInfo.getDefaultConfiguration();
            ICSourceEntry[] sourceEntries = activeConfig.getSourceEntries();
            Path newPath = new Path("dir name");sourceEntries = CDataUtil.setExcluded(newPath, true, exclude, sourceEntries);
              activeConfig.setSourceEntries(sourceEntries); This works except apply button. How to make apply programmatically??

Comment: After adding below line it worked as expected ManagedBuildManager.saveBuildInfo(project, true);